# 「指定したurlへ遷移する」のサンプルコードが実行できません

Tags: python, windows, selenium, chromedriver

Python初心者です。
インターネットで調べました「指定したurlへ遷移する」のサンプルコード

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Desktop/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.yahoo.co.jp/")
```

をIDLEで実行したところ以下の表示がでました。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kenny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 72, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "C:\Users\kenny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\kenny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1416, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] 指定されたファイルが見つかりません。

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/kenny/Desktop/test.py", line 2, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Desktop/chromedriver.exe")
  File "C:\Users\kenny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\kenny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

また、以下のコードに書き直したところ、

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome
driver.get("https://www.yahoo.co.jp/")
```

今度は以下の表示がされました。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/kenny/Desktop/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver.get("https://www.yahoo.co.jp/")
TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'
```

selenium、Chromedriverはインストール済です。
色々試しましたが、どうしてもうまくいかないので質問させていただきました。
全くの初心者ですが宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

直接的な原因は、`driver = webdriver.Chrome`で後ろに`()`が付いていないことだと思われます。
以下のようにしてみてください。

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.yahoo.co.jp/")
```

---

ただし、今は更にその先で`Chrome`か`ChromeDriver`の版数の影響かもしれない別の問題が発生しているようです。
Chromeの版数は88.0.4324.150
ChromeDriverの版数は88.0.4324.96

こんなエラーが表示されます。

```
>>> [4940:10520:0215/120439.701:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)] [12:04:39.702] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1049 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: システムに接続されたデバ イスが機能していません。 (0x1F)
```

ChromeDriverの版数を１つ古い88.0.4324.27に変えても発生しました。
Chromeの問題の可能性が高いですが、古い版数のインストーラを持っていないと対処が大変ですね。
[Chrome のバージョンをダウングレードする（Windows）](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7125792?hl=ja)

一応上記のエラーが出ても処理の継続は出来るようです。

@kenny2021jp さんの環境でエラーが発生するかどうかは不明ですが、発生する場合はとりあえずエラーは無視して使い続けるか、修正されるまではこちらの記事を参考に`FireFox`と`geckodriver`で代替してみるとかでしょうか。
[Windows 10 + Python3 + selenium + geckodriver で headless Firefox を試してみる](https://qiita.com/tabizou/items/60e0d2cb0ef050f6193c)
ちなみに現在の[geckodriverの最新版](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.29.0)は0.29.0です。

---

この記事によると Chrome v87 から発生していて Chrome v90 で直るそうです。
[USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1020 Failed to read descriptor from node connection error with ChromeDriver v87 / Chrome v87 using Selenium on Windows10](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65080685/9014308)

そのコメントに`chrome://flags`で`Enable new USB backend`を有効にするとメッセージが出なくなったというのがありますが、試したところでは駄目で依然としてエラーメッセージは表示されます。(Chrome自身もcanary版にする必要があったのかもしれませんが、それはしていません)

日本語ではこんな記事もあります。無視しても動いているようですね。
[seleniumでのログイン自動化のエラー【ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)】](https://teratail.com/questions/310277)
[【Python初心者】PythonとSeleniumで、Chromeを使用しAmazonログインページから自動ログイン](https://laboratory.kazuuu.net/python-selenium-amazon-login-automatic-operation/)
[Seleniumを使用しPythonでWebページのタイトルを取得する](https://laboratory.kazuuu.net/get-web-page-titles-in-python-using-selenium/)